# Check if a a formated table with style has no data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formatted table with style named "Goals". And I have a counter to check how many rows has the table. Every time a row is added or deleted the counter updates.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("Goals").Rows(1) = Empty Then
    Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = 0
Else
    Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = Range("Goals").Rows.Count
End If

End Sub
```

If the table is populated and all rows are deleted, which result in a table with no data, the condition `Range("Goals").Rows(1) = Empty` is evaluated as `False` and the counter doesn't update properly. However, if the table has one row of data, and the cell is erased manually (without deleted the row of the table) the `counter` does update correctly, and I dont know why.

I've tried evaluating the condition as `Worksheets(GoalsList).Cells(2,1) = Empty`, but it doesn't work either.

Please help, I don't know what to do!

Comment: `Range("Goals")` refers to a `Names Range` that is named "Goals", not a Table, which in VBA is a `ListObject` , so which one do you have in your worksheet ?

Comment: I have a Table named "Goals". Why is working Range?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Excel Table with name "Table1" you can find the last row with data based on it's column 1 data like below...

```
Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

If you have created a Named Range called "Golas" which refers to the whole Excel Table, you may try...

```
Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = Range("Goals").Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

To check if the table exists, try something like below...

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
On Error Resume Next
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Goals")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.ListObjects("Goals").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells)
End If
```

Comment: Hi, i tried both codes,but the problem remains. It happens only when the table "Goals" is populated with only 1 row, and if that row is deleted, then the counter doesn't update to 0. If i make another change on the worksheet, then the counter updates correctly to 0. I need the counter updates inmediately after deleting the row of data, without have to make another change in the Worksheet

Comment: The both the codes include the column header of the table as well. So they will return 1 if no cell in first column of the table has data in it. Therefore you should subtract 1 i.e. ws.ListObjects("Table1").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 1

Comment: Yes, I considered that, your codes and my code works fine. It happens only when the table "Goals" is populated with just 1 row, and if that row is deleted, then the counter doesn't update to 0. I have to make another change in the Workhseet i.e. write on a cell. to getthe counter  updated correctrly. If table is populated with 2, 3 .... rows and I deleted all rows, then the counter updates correctly.

Comment: What about  Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.ListObjects("Goals").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells) ?

Comment: It looks like deleting the only one row of the table, is not identified as a change by `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: `Worksheets("Counters").Cells(2, 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.ListObjects("Goals").DataBodyRan‌​ge.Columns(1).Cells)`. Neither

Comment: If I test the proposed code with a dummy table, it works at my end. :)

Comment: If I delete all rows I got `Error 91 Object variable not set`

Comment: You need to check if the table exists and then proceed further in the code. I have edited my answer, please check that.

Comment: Yes, table exists